# Двойной tab-content

Tags: javascript

Появилась очень интересная задачка, - есть обычная ТАБ конструкция от 3 бутстрапа
https://jsbin.com/naqofimaka/

Необходимо, открывать два таба одновременно с этим же названием.
В текущей конструкции открывается только один таб, а необходимо открывать два

То есть,  одно меню:
`<li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>`

и есть два таба
`<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
 <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">`

при нажатии на `menu1`, открывается только один таб, а необходимо открывать сразу два, соответственно, когда нажимается `menu2`, то оба таба скрываются.

Как это сделать?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Pills</h2>
  <p>To make the tabs toggleable, add the data-toggle="pill" attribute to each link. Then add a .tab-pane class with a unique ID for every tab and wrap them inside a div element with class .tab-content.</p>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Два элемента не могут иметь одинаковый id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На странице не может работать больше одного id. Если их несколько - выбирается первый найденный (с). Это дело можно решить (например) через классы - добавляя уникальные классы тем элементам, которые нужно открыть. Но можно немного схитрить и добавить не абы-какие, а с номерами - чтобы класс открываемой вкладки удачно совпадал с номером кликнутой кнопки (в JS счет начинается от 0, 1, 2...) поэтому tab0, tab1, tab2 - в соответствии с кнопками.

(код мог бы быть короче, но так по моему смысл более очевиден) — Сперва перебираем и закрываем вообще все вкладки (даже те, которые и так закрыты), убираем активный класс со всех кнопок, а уже потом добавляем класс на текущую кликнутую, открываем нужные вкладки.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/fhx06twv/)

```js
(function(){
//Сохранили все кнопки и все вкладки...
const link = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
const tab  = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
let tabN;
//Перебираем все кнопки и кругами вешаем на них событие 'клик'
//Плюс такого варианта в том, что при клике сразу определяется номер кнопки = это [i]
for(let i = 0; i < link.length; i++){
  link[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    //Перебираем все вкладки и сперва делаем их всех невидимыми
    for(let u = 0; u < tab.length; u++){
      tab[u].style.display = 'none';
    }
    //Перебираем все кнопки и убираем с них "активный" класс
    for(let u = 0; u < link.length; u++){
      link[u].classList.remove('active');
    }
    
    //Добавляем активный класс на текущую кликнутую кнопку 
    this.classList.add('active');

    //Изначально задали переменную tabN для этого: 
    //Ему приписываем классы 'tab' + i, причем - после клика кнопки, это i сразу
    //становится определенным числом - 0, 1, 2... таким образом если кликнута первая
    //кнопка, получается здесь написано то же, что и 
  //tabN = document.getElementsByClassName('tab0');
    tabN = document.getElementsByClassName('tab' + i);
    //Вот и перебираем нужные нам классы и всех их делаем видимыми.
    for(let u = 0; u < tabN.length; u++){
      tabN[u].style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
}

})();
```

```css
.tab {display: none; margin: 10px;}

.active {color: red;}
```

```html
<button class="link">1111</button>
<button class="link">2222</button>
<button class="link">3333</button>

<div class="tab tab0">bubu - 1</div>
<div class="tab tab1">bubu - 2</div>
<div class="tab tab2">bubu - 3</div>

<div class="tab tab0">kuku - 1</div>
<div class="tab tab1">kuku - 2</div>
<div class="tab tab2">kuku - 3</div>

<div class="tab tab0">dudu - 1</div>
<div class="tab tab1">dudu - 2</div>
<div class="tab tab2">dudu - 3</div>
```

Если вкладок будет 100500, можно еще схитрить и заранее прописать еще одну переменную `let previuos;` и в самом конце клика добавить `previous = i;`. Тогда вначале клика можно будет скрывать табы не полным перебором всех подряд, а использовав сохраненное число из предыдущего клика - скрыть только открытые.

Comment: если на странице одинаковые id, то выбирается первый найденный и обычно это первый

Comment: @Дмытрык и правда... https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/zkv1u6qd/ и CSS почему-то срабатывает на всех))

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME спасибо тебе огромное, то что нужно!